# "Invalid Credentials" when accessing Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm developing an AppEngine application which lists files from my Google Drive using the Google Drive API. I'm getting an 500 error when one of my users tries to run my app:

HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%27[ID sanitized]%27+in+parents&alt=json&maxResults=5 returned "Invalid Credentials">

The code pulls files from a specific google drive folder. The folder and files are shared with the user, and the app is authorized to use the Google Drive API.

At some point, I figured that I should start from scratch, so I revoked the authorization from that user's account. Didn't seem to make a difference and now to add insult over injury it appears that my app no longer asks that particular user for authorization.

Does anybody have any recommendations at this point?  My code uses the Google API client for python and the decorators (with oauth_required) for handling authorization:

```
CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json')

MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
<h1>Warning: Please configure OAuth 2.0</h1>
<p>
To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:
</p>
<p>
<code>%s</code>.
</p>
<p>with information found on the <a
href="https://code.google.com/apis/console">APIs Console</a>.
</p>
""" % CLIENT_SECRETS

http = httplib2.Http(memcache)

service = build("plus", "v1", http=http)
files_service = build("drive", "v2", http=http)

decorator = oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets(
    CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

[...]

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):

[...]

        try:
            kb_param = {}
            kb_param["maxResults"] = 5
            kb_param["q"] = "'[sanitized]' in parents"
            kb_files = files_service.files().list(**kb_param).execute(http=http)

            template_values = {
                'kb_files': kb_files["items"]
            }
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks!
Rick.

Answer (score 0):

The token might be revoked, or the credentials might actually be wrong.